# VS 2010, Move constructor only reached after move() and slower than copy constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11

trying to test out move semantics i build a simple class that allocates some memory:

```
class CTest
{
    private:
        std::size_t size;
        char* buffer;

    public:
        CTest(std::size_t size) : size(size), buffer(nullptr)
        {
            buffer = new char[size];
        }

        ~CTest()
        {
            delete[] buffer;
        }

        CTest(const CTest& other) : size(other.size), buffer(nullptr)
        {
            buffer = new char[size];
        }

        CTest(CTest&& other) : size(other.size), buffer(other.buffer)
        {
            other.buffer = nullptr;
        }
};
```

as you can see its a very simple class that when it copies by ref it allocates new memory (doesnt copy its contents tho, just for testing).
and the move constructor just makes the internal pointer pointing to the argument data, no new memory is allocated.

for benchmarking im using windows QueryPerformanceCounter() with a helper function like:

```
template <typename Func>
__int64 Benchmark(Func f, size_t count)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li = {};
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    __int64 start = li.QuadPart;

    f(count);

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return li.QuadPart - start;
}
```

very simple benchmark function, saves the starting time and subtracts it from the ending time and returns the result.
now for the testing functions:

```
void Alloc_Ref(size_t count)
{
    CTest t(1024);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        CTest c(t);
}

void Alloc_Move(size_t count)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        CTest c(CTest(1024));
}
```

the Alloc_Ref one uses a pre-initialized variable so it calls the copy constructor and the Alloc_Move one simply uses a temporary class, so it calls the move constructor.

im calling the test like this:

```
cout << "Ref: " << Benchmark(Alloc_Ref, 1000000) << " ms." << endl;
cout << "Move: " << Benchmark(Alloc_Move, 1000000) << " ms." << endl;
```

problem is, Alloc_Move is not calling the move constructor, it continues to call the copy constructor, is there something im missing?

also equally important, when i do this on the Alloc_Move: `CTest c(move(CTest(1024))` it does call the move constructor BUT its slower than the Alloc_Ref one, again is there something im missing?

sorry the long post and thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In order to take advantage of move semantics, you need to explicitly use rvalue references. For compatibility with older code, the compiler will never implicitly cast to an rvalue reference for you; you need to either use `std::move` or explicitly cast.

Your `Alloc_Move` is most likely slower because you're constructing a new `CTest(1024)` each time you construct `c`, where as `Alloc_Ref` only constructs a single `CTest(1024)` and reuses it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. so everytime i want to use the move constructor i have to call move() even if its already a rvalue reference (for instance a function return value)? in other words, even if i do A a(b.getA()) since b.getA() is a temporary right, i still have to call move() on it?

Comment: But each time `Alloc_Ref` reuses the `CTest(1024)` it allocates a new batch of memory anyway. And **no** you don't need to use `std::move` everywhere. Temporaries bind to rvalue references automatically. I think the reason it isn't happening here is due to a bug in the VS compiler.

Comment: yes i forgot i was allocating the memory every time i initialized the temporary, that was really bad programming by me, thanks for poiting that out.

Comment: @sap: It depends what `getA()` returns. If your type is already an rvalue reference (T&&), you can just use it as it is. If it's not, you need to pass it through `move`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Maybe it is a VS bug; I only develop for Windows, so I wouldn't know if the behavior is different on other compilers. Using cl, `Alloc_Ref` would allocate twice and `Alloc_Move` would allocate three times.

Comment: -1: "In order to take advantage of move semantics, you need to explicitly use rvalue references." Untrue. Temporaries are prvalues; they are always moveable from. They will bind to r-value references *implicitly*. If VC10 doesn't move from them, then VC10 has a bug in it.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is, `Alloc_Move` is not calling the move constructor, it continues to call the copy constructor, is there something im missing?

Your analysis is incorrect.  If you are using the Visual C++ 2010 SP1 compiler, `Alloc_Move` calls neither the copy constructor nor the move constructor.  The declaration and initialization

```
CTest c(CTest(1024));
```

is transformed into

```
CTest c(1024);
```

That is, `c` is directly initialized by calling the constructor `CTest(std::size_t size)`.  No temporary `CTest` objects are created or destroyed.

---

On my Visual Studio 2010 32-bit VM, I see about a 20% difference in performance between your `Alloc_Move` and `Alloc_Ref` functions (the latter being faster).  I took a brief glance at the generated assembly but did not see any obvious cause of the difference.  With the Visual C++ 11 Beta compiler (for x86), `Alloc_Move` is well over twice as fast as `Alloc_Ref` (I haven't investigated further, and I don't know what the reason is).

[Note also that your measurement units are wrong:  `QueryPerformanceCounter` does not return milliseconds; it returns ticks.  You need to call [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the number of ticks per second, then divide your measurements accordingly.]